# Oracle Homework - LPAD / RPAD Error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a statement that will produce "Oracle$$$Internet$$$Academy" using LPAD and RPAD commands. this is what I have so far, but I am getting a missing right parenthesis error.

```
SELECT LPAD(RPAD('Oracle', 10,'$$$')RPAD('Internet',24,'$$$'))
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Actually you've lost concatenation `||`. After you fix that - you'll experience an issue with insufficient parameters passed to outer `LPAD`. Also you probably don't want `$$$` but do want `$` - padding functions were invented to calculate necessary amount characters for you. So probably you need to read a documentation once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to use both RPAD and LPAD?   If not, you are simply missing the concatenation characters of ||

```
SELECT RPAD('Oracle', 9,'$$$')||RPAD('Internet',11,'$$$')||'Academy' FROM dual
```

EDIT: Even better:

```
SELECT RPAD('Oracle', 9,'$$$')||'Internet'||LPAD('Academy',10,'$$$') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use both `LPAD` and `RPAD` you could do something like this.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT RPAD('Oracle', length('Oracle')+3,'$')||
  2         'Internet' ||
  3         LPAD('Academy', length('Academy')+3, '$' )
  4*   FROM dual
SQL> /

RPAD('ORACLE',LENGTH('ORACL
---------------------------
Oracle$$$Internet$$$Academy
```

I'm using the length of the strings 'Oracle' and 'Academy' rather than hard-coding values.  And I'm only specifying the dollar sign once-- `LPAD` and `RPAD` automatically take care of appending it the proper number of times.